# CiviCRM is defaulting to uppercase path

Tags: wordpress, links, redirect

Somehow CiviCRM is wanting to use the path /CiviCRM (notice the case) instead of all lowercase civicrm.  This has been fine until I upgraded to Civi 5.27 and now the civicrm?civiwp implementation results in a 404.  I can change the case manually and it will work but the automatically generated URLs use all lowercase.

For example:
https://www.domain.org/civicrm?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=24  == 404 Not Found

https://www.domain.org/CiviCRM/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=24 == working

This is also breaking images in my Mosaico templates.

Example of a Mosaico image:
https://www.domain.org/civicrm?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmosaico%2Fimg&src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fcivicrm%2Fpersist%2Fcontribute%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2Fdcs_e1de5c0ee5de2a85bb86821132d2aaba.png&method=resize&params=166%2Cnull

If you change the link to /CiviCRM?civiwp=CiviCRM.... it works.

I have verified that the permalink on the page is lowercase as well as the CMS Database Integration in Civi.  Has anyone seen this behavior or have any suggestions for how I can correct it?

**UPDATE:**

Adding the following lines to my htaccess fixes this as a workaround.  Still not sure why it is defaulting to CiviCRM instead of civicrm.  Hopefully if this is happening to you, you can use this patch.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/civicrm(.*)$ /$1/CiviCRM/$2 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a .htaccess workaround but I have tested and verified that it works.  Please the following in your root .htaccess file or httpd-app.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/civicrm(.*)$ /$1/CiviCRM/$2 [R=301,L]
```

If someone from the community cares enough to look into why this is defaulting to CiviCRM when everything is set to civicrm, please do.  Otherwise this band-aid will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the CMS Settings `https://yoursite.org//wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1` and see what you see?

I suspect it looks like:

[image]

Can you also check the WP Page 'CiviCRM'  I suspect the slug is not 'civicrm' lowercase.   These values must match in order for the urls to resove.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the quick reply.  Both the page slug and Base Page are lowercase.  I've updated my question with the screenshots of each.

Comment: That is really odd.  As they both match it should work.  Is it possible there is a civicrm folder in the web root

Comment: Even stranger is that if you go to /civicrm it gives you a server side 404.  If you go to any other non existent folder (ie. /civistack) it will serve a html page 404.  I can't even do a 301 rewrite for the /civicrm folder to force it to CiviCRM.  This is really strange.

Comment: Can anyone add further suggestions or insight?  This is breaking Mosaico templates and we're not able to send mailings.  See the two new examples in the original post.  
Could I use a rewrite in the htaccess to rewrite all requests for civicrm?civiwp= to CiviCRM?civiwp= ? If so, how would I do that?  Thanks!

Comment: Partial answer... adding the following in htaccess fixes the links but breaks the admin pages for civi... getting closer to a workaround...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/civicrm(.*)$ /CiviCRM/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/civicrm(.*)$ /$1/CiviCRM/$2 [R,L]